# Convert UTF-8 characters to NCR Iconv

Tags: bash, utf-8, iconv, ncr

I'm trying to convert UTF-8 characters from a file to [NCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) Hexadecimal. I tried the following:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t //TRANSLIT file --unicode-subst=&#x%04X;'
```

However, it doesn't do anything, and I can't even find the appropriate encoding name for NCR in `iconv --list`.

Comment: Can you clarify what result you expect from "NCR"?

Comment: @deceze I expect UTF-8 characters to be converted to NCR HEX. For example, a space should translate to "&#x20;".

Comment: Anyway, this does not look like a job for `iconv`, you do not want to change encoding, only the way the information is presented. It looks like a job for C or python or other UTF-aware languages - read one codepoint, and output it with `&#x$04X`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought so. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want *HTML entities*…‽